# React Material UI TextField value is not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

There are four files: createPollForm.js, formOptions.js, optionList.js, and option.js

**createPollForm has a state of option array with initial value:**

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState([{
        id: uuidv4(),
        value: ""
    }]);

const handleOptionsChange = value => {
       setOptions(value);
}

return(
        <FormOptions 
               options={options}
               handleOptionsChange={handleOptionsChange}
        />
)
```

**formOptions.js receives handleOptionsChange from createPollForm.js :**

```
const handleValue = id => {
      const result = options.filter(option => option.id === id)
      return result[0].value
}

const handleChangeValue = (e, id) => {
      options.forEach(option => {
          if(option.id === id){
              option.value = e.target.value
          }
      })

      handleOptionsChange(options)
}

return (
     <OptionList 
            options={options}
            handleValue={handleValue}
            handleChangeValue={handleChangeValue}
     />
)
```

**optionList.js contains all the option TextFields**

```
return (
        <div>
            {options.map(option => (
                <Option 
                    key={option.id} 
                    id={option.id}
                    handleValue={handleValue}
                    handleChangeValue={handleChangeValue}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
```

option.js:

```
return(
       <TextField 
           label="Option"
           value={props.handleValue(props.id)}
           onChange={e => props.handleChangeValue(e, props.id)}
       />
    )
```

Before adding the value in TextField in option.js, everything works fine, however, after **adding the value with the handleValue function** for assigning value to each option TextField, the TextField will just remain **blank** when I am typing in the corresponding TextField even though I can see the **value of option array state** is updated through console.log. Therefore, I assume for some reason the TextField has trouble to read the most updated value from option array.

Could anyone help me with this? I just started learning reactjs, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In handleOptionsChange method in createPollForm.js. update state like given:

```
setOptions({...options,value})
```

because initial value is object, and you passing value.

Comment: I pass the array object of option to the handleOptionsChange() in handleChangeValue() in formOptions.js